# need to create salary data with salary bands

Tags: excel, graph, charts, scatter-plot

looking to create a salary chart for all my employees.  should be xy scatter plot with all salary data for my employees grouped by their title.  I want floating bar graph representing salary range for that title.

salary data:

employee,title,salary
joe, eng 1, 15000
mike, eng 1, 16000
kelly, eng 3, 25000
steve, eng 2, 20000
jane, eng 3, 30000
michelle, eng 5, 60000
anan, eng 5, 70000

eng level salary band

title,min, max
eng 1, 10000, 20000
eng 2, 15000, 30000
eng 3, 25000, 40000
eng 4, 30000, 60000
eng 5, 50000, 80000
eng 6, 60000, 100000

note i wont have employees in every level, but want to show that level on the chart,  the levels should be shown left to right on the graph from eng 1 to eng 6

i am having a hard time to figure out how to do this in excel...your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll make a floating bar chart with the salary bands, then overlay XY scatter points with the individual data.

First, insert a column between min and max salary in the bands table, and use a formula to compute the span between max and min, as shown below. Select the shaded range and insert a stacked column chart. It looks like the top chart below.

Format the chart as follows: Remove the title (or enter something useful). Remove the legend. Change the number format of the vertical axis to 0,"k" (the comma knocks off a set of three zeros). Format the Min series with no border and no fill, so it is invisible. Format the Span series to use a lighter fill color. Change the gap width of the Span series to something like 75.

[image: salary band data and initial charts]

Insert a column that contains the number of the salary band (or just change "eng X" to "X") as shown below left. Copy the shaded range, select the chart, choose Paste Special from the Paste dropdown on the Home tab of the ribbon, and use the options shown in the dialog below right (add cells as new series, series in columns, series names in first row, category labels in first column). The chart looks like it got a new set of stacked bars; we'll fix it shortly.

[image: individual salary data and updated charts]

Right click the added series, choose Change Series Chart Type, and choose the XY Scatter style with markers and no lines (below left). Select the new series with markers, press the Ctrl+1 shortcut to format it, choose Primary axis, so it aligns nicely with the existing floating bars, and choose a format that stands out. I used a dark blue marker border and white marker fill (bottom left). Add labels using the Excel 2013 option, Label contains value from cells, or in older versions of Excel, install Rob Bovey's Chart Labeler add-in (free from http://appspro.com) to add arbitrary labels. Also, you should stretch the chart vertically to add resolution (below right).

[image: finish up the chart]